# Alpha Over .png file pixelated after adding it to Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, import

After I add the Alpha Over png file to my VSE it is pixelated. 
Maybe you could have a quick look into the files and show me my error:

[image: Alpha Over png file]

[image: After Importing in VSE]

Alpha Over Image File: [image]

VSE with Image File: [image]

Thanks in advance!
Appreciate any help.

Cheers

Comment: Why did you downvote my Question? Rather give me hints on how to improve it then please .

Comment: I would suggest adding more information than two files to your question. As it stands now, users will need to download your file to gain any understanding of your scene. Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/106705/edit) your question and add more details, in particular, images that would be useful in describing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Added some images now. And I thought the files were as much detailed as it can get. ^^

Comment: this looks like a premultiplication issue. Read the second last paragraph from this section of the manual: https://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/editors/sequencer/effects.html#alpha-over-under-and-over-drop

Answer (score 0):

In the filter layout, try setting the "Convert to Float" value to True. Also try Enabling "Deinterlace". Put the Text image over your black color and make sure it's blend mode is set to "Alpha".

[image]

Your Example Blend files didn't have the text images in them, so I couldn't make sure my advice would help.

It could also be that your text image isn't high enough resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The image is good.

In this particular case, the issue is not an issue.

It's caused by a stripe with a blend opacity animation.

Captured images below.

[image]